# enigma using python-multiprocessing related with if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using `multiprocessing` to speed up my program and there is an enigma I can not solve.
I am using `multiprocessing` to write a lot of short files (based on a lot of input files) with the function `writing_sub_file`, and I finally concatenate all these files after the end of all the processes, using the function `my_concat`. Here are two samples of code. Note that this code is in my `main .py` file, but the function `my_concat` is imported from another module. The first one:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    arg_tuple = (work_path, article_dict, cat_len, date_to, time_period, val_matrix)
    jobs = [(group, arg_tuple) for group in store_groups]
    pool.apply_async(writing_sub_file, jobs)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

my_concat(work_path)
```

which gives many errors (as many as there are processes in the pool) since It tries to apply `my_concat` before all my processes are done (I don't give the stack of the error since It is very clear that `my_concat` function tries to apply before every files have been written by the pool processes).

The second one:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    arg_tuple = (work_path, article_dict, cat_len, date_to, time_period, val_matrix)
    jobs = [(group, arg_tuple) for group in store_groups]
    pool.apply_async(writing_sub_file, jobs)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    my_concat(work_path)
```

which works perfectly.

Can someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second, `my_concat(work_path)` is inside the `if` statement, and is therefore only executed if the script is running as the main script.

In the first, `my_concat(work_path)` is outside the `if` statement. When `multiprocessing` imports the module in a new Python session, it is not imported as `__main__` but under its own name.  Therefore this statement is run pretty much immediately, in each of your pool's processes, when your module is imported into that process.

Comment: oh I see... So I should keep everything under the if name == main? What is the best way to wait for all processes to finish then execute my_concat?

Comment: @user3478208 Yes, you need to keep everything under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard. It looks like you're not really using `multiprocessing` properly, though. You're sending *all* of your jobs to one worker process, waiting for that one process to finish processing all of them, then concatenating them in the parent. That's not going to speed things up at all, it'll actually slow you down a bit because of the IPC overhead required to send all of `writing_sub_file`'s arguments to the child process. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to treat every files in my store and transform it into a "treated file" (i would have 100 of them), and then concatenate all the treated files in a single one. My idea was to use multiprocessing to treat all the files in my store, then wait untill they are all treated, then go back to a single process and concatenate the treated files in a single big file and then continue a treatment in a single process. What should I change?